# Problems using two OSGI applications in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, osgi, birt, eclipse-rap

whenever I start and access BIRT and an Eclipse RAP application deployed in Tomcat, Tomcat "crashes" (does not accept any new requests). This does not always happen immediately after the first access, but eventually it happens.

If I only run one of both applications, it works fine.

Memory and CPU load are ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RAP application used the Oracle JDBC driver ojcdb14.jar while BIRT uses ojdbc6.jar.
The problem seems to be related to that, as tomcat logs showed a ClassNotFoundException for the Oracle driver for BIRT, while however the BIRT reports correctly were able to access the database so the driver must be loaded somehow.

I updated the JDBC driver used by the RAP application and by now, both applications run concurrently without problems longer than ever.